# Fluent API - one to many

Tags: entity-framework-5

I cannot seem to find a one-to-many relationship syntax in the fluent API.

As an example I have two tables as below

**User**

```
Id
Name
```

**UserHistory**

```
Id
UserId
Date
```

In the classes I have the following

```
public class User 
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public virtual ICollection<UserHistory> Histories { get; set; }
}

public class UserHistory
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public int UserId { get; set; }
     public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

I have tried the following but I am not sure if its actually correct.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
       .HasRequired(w => w.Histories)
       .WithMany();

modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
       .HasMany(f => f.Histories)
       .WithOptional()
       .HasForeignKey(f => f.UserId);
```

What is the correct syntax for one-to-many relationship?

Technically I could break it down to a many-to-many by adding a new table but I didn't want to introduce another table.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In your model a `User` entity **has many** `Histories` **with** each history having a **required** `User` and the relationship **has** a **foreign key** called `UserId`:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
   .HasMany(u => u.Histories)
   .WithRequired()
   .HasForeignKey(h => h.UserId);
```

(The relationship must be required (not optional) because the foreign key property `UserId` is not nullable.)

Comment: If the UserHistory UserId was nullable, then it would be WithOptional()?

Comment: is this how you'd define the one to many relationship now in 2019? Can't find any good example anywhere

Comment: @matt I agree, I cannot find an updated guide as to how to make such a relationship