# .Net Core Entity Framework - Read Multiple Objects

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, sqlite, .net-core

I did use the code first programming pattern with the entity Framework in .net core. I created a database which works really great and I can save data to it.

The data is saved in an SQLite Database. When I take a look at the Database I see that there are columns inserted and the data is available.

Now I would like to read Data from the Database. 
In this case I am using following code:

```
DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext();
MicroserviceMetric result = db.MicroserviceMetrics.LastOrDefault();
```

The Database Context is the Context which represents the Database. There is a MicroserviceMetrics DbSet which holds different classes of the Type MicroserviceMetric. This class also have some different Objects and Lists, but anyway the Data could be inserted in a correct way.

But the example at top Returns only as a result the primitive datatype Primary key which is represented as an integer. The other objects are not readable and there is a null, although the data is available in the database.

I tried a lot of different things, but it doesn't work.

Comment: You need to tell EF to include the other database-tables. If you have a foreign key to the table `Microservice` in `MicroserviceMetrics`, you can include the Microservice like this:
`var result = db.MicroserviceMetrics.Include(x => x.Microservice).LastOrDefault();`

Comment: First of all, i don't have the Method **Include**! Another Point is, that i don't have the foreign key to the table becouse it was code first development and the keys are autogenerated. Other possiblities?

Comment: You need to add `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;` to get `Include`

Comment: You might also want to describe the relationship with the Fluent API. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14295957/2559626)