# EF Core FK Constraint on Alternate Key

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

Hi I have an entity as below

```
public class SalaryTransactionAudit
{
      public long SalaryTransactionAuditId { get; set; }
      public Guid TransactionBatchId { get; set; }
      public DateTime UploadedDate { get; set; }
      public string UploadedBy { get; set; }
      public long SalaryTransactionStatusId { get; set; }
}
```

The above entity has primary key on **SalaryTransactionAuditId**  and Alternate Key on **TransactionBatchId**  as below

```
public class SalaryTransactionAuditConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<SalaryTransactionAudit>
{
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<SalaryTransactionAudit> builder)
        {
            builder.ToTable("SalaryTransactionAudit");
            builder.HasKey(e => e.SalaryTransactionAuditId);
            builder.HasAlternateKey(e => e.TransactionBatchId);
        }
 }
```

And I also have this entity

```
public class SalaryTransaction
 {
        public long SalaryTransactionId { get; set; }
        public Guid TransactionBatchId { get; set; }
        public long EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public int AnnualSalary { get; set; }
        public int SuperRate { get; set; }
        public int PaymentPeriodYear { get; set; }
        public int PaymentPeriodMonth { get; set; }

        public Employee Employee { get; set; }
   }
```

How do I configure (using fluent API) for FK Constraint on **TransactionBatchId** something like below

```
public class SalaryTransactionConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<SalaryTransaction>
{
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<SalaryTransaction> builder)
        {
            builder.ToTable("SalaryTransaction");
            builder.HasKey(e => e.SalaryTransactionId);
            builder.HasForeignKey(e => e.TransactionBatchId );

        }
}
```

Comment: what is the relation between the batch and transaction, 1 to many or 1 to 1?

Comment: 1 to Many is the relationship

Comment: Please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14295705/fluent-api-one-to-many

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Foregn / principal keys of a relationship are configured via relationship builders `HasForeignKey` / `HasPrincipalKey` fluent API.

It would be good if you add navigation property at least to one of the related entities. But with the current model, and assuming the relationship is one-to-many, it could be something like this:

Inside `SalaryTransactionConfiguration` class

```
builder
    .HasOne<SalaryTransactionAudit>()
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.TransactionBatchId)
    .HasPrincipalKey(e => e.TransactionBatchId);
```

or inside `SalaryTransactionAuditConfiguration` class

```
builder
    .HasMany<SalaryTransaction>()
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.TransactionBatchId)
    .HasPrincipalKey(e => e.TransactionBatchId);
```

Relationships always have two ends, so when using entity type configuration classes, put the configuration in either of them, but not both (to avoid redundant or confliction configuration for  one and the same relationship). Also make sure to use `Has` / `With` methods correctly, i.e. with or without navigation property expression depending of whether it exists or not.

Comment: It should be noted that nullable values aren't permitted for an alternate key field, see [Optional alternate key properties](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/4415) issue and upvote if you need this ability.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use DataAnnotation something like this:

```
public Guid TransactionBatchId { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("TransactionBatchId")]  
public SalaryTransactionAudit SalaryTransactionAudit { get; set; }
```

See also: [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships)

Comment: I don't believe this is correct, it would try to map the [TransactionBatchId] field to the primary key field on the SalaryTransactionAudit table which is [SalaryTransactionAuditId].